# Why calculating expected value of one part of a joint PDF alters bounds of one of the PDF variables?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

So given a joint pdf given by $f(y_1,y_2) = 6(1-y_2)$ with $0 \leq y_1 \leq y_2 \leq 1$ and trying to find $E(y_1)$

I used a double integral with the outer integral being from $(0,1)$ and the inner being from $(y_1,1)$. Why is it that the outer integral bounds become $(0,1)$ and not based on $y_2$ in a similar fashion to how the inner integral bounds are based on $y_1$? Is it because integrating over $y_2$ at first puts the outer integral "in terms of" only the $y_1$ dimension?

Comment: Draw a sketch of the domain of the joint distribution. Answer should be clear then.

Comment: I think I get it now. Is it because you put the "area" of one dimension of the function in the inner integral in a way that it is dependent on the dimension in the outer, and then the outer integral is used to apply that "area" under the function to the last dimension of the graph so you can get the "volume" under it?

Answer (score 1):

The joint pdf rewrites
$$
f(y_1,y_2) = 6\left(1-y_2\right) \mathbf{1}_{0\leq y_1\leq y_2\leq 1} \, .
$$
The domain where the pdf is nonzero is a triangle in the $y_1$-$y_2$ plane, with surface area $1/2$. The marginal pdf writes
\begin{aligned}
g(y_1) &= \int_{\Bbb R} 6\left(1-y_2\right) \mathbf{1}_{0\leq y_1\leq y_2\leq 1}\, \text{d}y_2 \\
&= 6\, \mathbf{1}_{0\leq y_1\leq 1} \int_{y_1}^1 \left(1-y_2\right)\, \text{d}y_2 \\
&= 3\, \left( 1- y_1\right)^2\, \mathbf{1}_{0\leq y_1\leq 1} \, .
\end{aligned}
The expected value is therefore
$$
E(Y_1) = \int_{\Bbb R} y_1\, g(y_1)\,\text{d}y_1 = \frac{1}{4} \, .
$$